# Making Dexguard to do not remove unused resources

Tags: java, android, proguard, dexguard

I'm having a hard time with dexguard to make it to do not remove a resource I access this way:

> int resourceId=getResources().getIdentifier("pictures", "array", getActivity().getPackageName());

When I execute the application I get the following exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Array resource ID #0x0
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Array resource ID #0x0

I have used this directives in proguard-project.txt extracted from some related questions on stack overflow and solved nothing:

```
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keep class **.R$*
```

How can I tell dexguard to do not strip out this resource?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is about not removing unused resources, not removing them. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after talking with dexguard creator it seems this can be achieved just by using:

```
-keepresources array/pictures
-keepresources array/a_*
```

Hope others will find this usseful

Cheers.

Comment: is it working for you.i have face the same issue but not working for me in android studio

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm using android studio too.

Comment: but my side i am getting some of the images. dexguard shrinking process remove the some of the files. i kept in my dexguard file -keep class **.R
-keep class **.R$* {
     *;
}
#Keep the R
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
     *;
}
-keepclassmembers class **.R* {
     *;
}   but no use. some of images only dipslaying

Comment: It is difficult from here to know exactly what is happening. You can contact dexguard programmer. It is a really helpful person.

Comment: thanks for your replay.  my self i found an answer. just keep the resources and remove the shrinking option.